# Pruning the Find command

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, find

I have the following command I run to grab all users in /Users minus any admin account, guest, shared or beginning with a "."

```
find /Users -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name admin ! -name Shared ! -name administrator | grep "$a"
```

This is more curiosity than anything, but is there a way to combine the names I want to ignore, instead of typing "! -name admin ! -name Administrator ! -name Shared" etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-regex` option:

```
find /Users -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d \
    -not -regex '.*/\(admin\|Shared\|administrator\)' | grep "$a"
```